# Masonry plugin: how to center items container

Tags: jquery-masonry

I'm using this [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin.

I'd like to center items container in page. Here's an image:

[image: masonry centered/left]

The first layout is aligned to the left, the second is centered. I want to center it but don't know how.